# Django admin page not work properly and show weird look

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

Today I have updated Django to the latest version.

But for some reason when the logged in to the admin page, all I cans see is a weird-looking admin page.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h35HD.png)

how to solve this problem?

Comment: Remove your static folder, then run `manage.py collectstatic`.

Comment: @lucutzu33 not working

Comment: Also try clearing your browser's cache.

Comment: @lucutzu33 tried still not working

Comment: I suggest you update your question and include your settings.py and your apps' admin.py.